# Rust: How to do HTTP PUT of large files?

Tags: rust

In rust, I am using [ureq](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/fn.put.html) to do HTTP requests. Here's a working HEAD request:

```
let resp = ureq::head(&url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
if !resp.ok() {
    return false;
}
```

I see ureq [supports](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/index.html#functions) the verb PUT,`pub fn put(path: &str) -> Request` just not exactly sure how to use it. How do I pass it the file/filehandle/fullpath?

Here's how I do this in bash:

```
$ curl -v http://192.168.1.100:9193/  -T deleteme.mp4
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x1102880)
*   Trying 192.168.1.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x1102880)
* Connected to 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100) port 9193 (#0)
> PUT /deleteme.mp4 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.100:9193
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 779189
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Expire in 1000 ms for 0 (transfer 0x1102880)
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 23:57:41 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.100 left intact

$ curl -I http://192.168.1.100:9193/deleteme.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 779189
Date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 23:57:44 GMT
```

**Edit 1**

Since my files are huge, I cannot read it all into memory (exhaustion), instead I need bufio reader sort of thing in between. Below is the code I attempted, except it fails short. Creates an empty file on the receiver.

`Response[status: 500, status_text: Network Error]  PUT deleteme.mp4 wrote: 0 bytes, took: 70.4µs`

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

const FILE_NAME: &str = "/tmp/deleteme.mp4";

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let f = File::open(FILE_NAME)?;
    let mut buffered_reader = BufReader::new(f);
    let r = ureq::put("http://192.168.1.100:9193/deleteme.mp4").send(buffered_reader);
    println!("{:?}", r);

    println!("Bye!");

    Ok(())
}
```

How do I make the plumbing work between `BufReader` and `ureq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a HTTP request with non-empty body, you have to set either `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding` header. For example, there was a `Content-Length` header in your curl session.

[`ureq::Request::send_bytes`](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/struct.Request.html#method.send_bytes) and [`ureq::Request::send_string`](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/struct.Request.html#method.send_string) will set this header for you, but [`ureq::Request::send`](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/struct.Request.html#method.send) won't. You have to do it yourself:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let f = File::open("/tmp/deleteme.mp4")?;
    let metadata = f.metadata()?;
    let buffered_reader = BufReader::new(f);
    let r = ureq::put("http://192.168.1.100:9193/deleteme.mp4")
        .set("Content-Length", &metadata.len().to_string())
        .send(buffered_reader);
    println!("{:?}", r);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Spot on! Could you please also show how to do this with `Transfer-Encoding` header?

Comment: @struggling_learner `ureq` documentation actually has an [example for chunked encoding](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/index.html#transfer-encoding-chunked). If the HTTP server you use can handle chunked encoding, it should just work.

Comment: As of `ureq-1.5.0` I think it's automatically set. [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/algesten/ureq/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#150)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've read the file into memory, you can use the [send_bytes](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.11.2/ureq/struct.Request.html#method.send_bytes) function on the returned `Request` to send the request with those bytes as the body.

You can learn about reading files [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-02-reading-a-file.html).

Comment: Pls see Edit 1 in question.